# mysql passing data to in

Tags: mysql, casting, subquery

Basically I want to fetch some data from tblvw1. Another table contains possible ids within a column which is stored as concatenated string, for example: "1|2|3|4". 
Next I have tried to get the result by the following query:

```
SELECT x FROM tblname1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT REPLACE(content,'|',',') FROM tblname2 WHERE dataid = y )
```

AS result I only get the first value, the other data wasn't fetched. 
I suppose that the subquery will result in this form:

```
SELECT x FROM tblname1 WHERE id IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

but i want to have this subquery either as

```
 SELECT x FROM tblname1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

or

```
  SELECT x FROM tblname1 WHERE id IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Any Idea?

Comment: that's why you shouldn't store comma separated values

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the `find_in_set` function?

```
SELECT x FROM tblname1 t1
inner join tblname2 t2 on find_in_set (t1.id, REPLACE(t2.content,'|',',')) > 0
where t2.dataid = 'y';
```

The `find_in_set` function returns the position of the first argument within the second argument. If the result is >0, then the first argument has been found.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! Thanks CGritton.