# How to pass comma separated value in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, in-subquery, denormalized

I am using a sub query to get all qcodes and passing it as a parameter to another query in mysql. But inner query is returning value like -

```
SELECT qcodes FROM boardmst WHERE id=10

10002','10028','10031','10202','10226
```

so how to parse it to pass in another query with IN clause?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE qcodes IN (SELECT qcodes FROM boardmst WHERE id=10)
```

Comment: Your query looks fine.  Do you have an issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "But inner query is returning value like -"

Comment: It is returning value with single quote 10002','10028','10031','10202','10226. but single quote is unavailable in first and last position. It is considering whole as a string like "10002','10028','10031','10202','10226"

Comment: What is the datatype of `qcodes`? Also add the insert query for `boardmst` table.

Comment: what about find_in_set() function?                                                                                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061181/mysql-passing-data-to-in

Comment: datatype is varchar

Comment: what is the result of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE qcodes IN (SELECT qcodes FROM boardmst WHERE id=10);`?

Comment: both have varchar datatype, problem it that it is taking it as a single string

Comment: This query fetches nothing "SELECT * FROM users WHERE qcodes IN (SELECT qcodes FROM boardmst WHERE id=10)" . but when i am passing parameter manually like - "SELECT * FROM users WHERE qcodes IN ('10002','10028','10031','10202','10226')" It fetches some results...

Comment: Are you running this query with some PDO or PreparedStatement in any language? Or you running directly on database?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing quotes on the outside (maybe it's not the exact answer the inner question produces) this is exactly what MySQL expects as the content of an IN clause. You just have to be sure that the definition of the *qcodes* column is identical between the **users** and the **boardmst** tables.

Comment: both have varchar datatype

Answer (score 0):

If you have only five values as comma separated then below query can come in handy :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE qcodes IN (
select regexp_substr(replace(qcodes,''',''',','),'[^, ]+',1,level)
from boardmst where id = 10 connect by level <= 5)
```